# Why does my macro changes all my currency formatted cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, format, currency

I'm writing a macro to loop thru some excel-files, in a specific directory, to update some values in each file. The value to be updated is located on a worksheet which name is the same in every file. The worksheet I try to update is protected in every file. My problem is when I update those files (I only have to unprotect it) and save my changes, all cells (in entire workbook) that I have formatted as 'currency' or 'accounting' and which contain a formula will be formatted as 'Custom'. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

EDIT: If I stop my macro before closing the file (opened by the macro) and then save the updated file manually, all my formatted cells have the correct format when I open it again.

This is my simplest code I have tried:

```
Sub moveBill()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim objFs As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim folder As String
Dim fileCount As Integer
Dim pw As String

pw = "1234"

folder = "C:\Excel-test"

Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFs.GetFolder(folder)

fileCount = 0
    
' Loop through all the files in the folder.
For Each file In objFolder.Files
    If Left(file.Name, 12) <> "FINAL REPORT" Then
        Dim src As Workbook         ' The source workbook.
        
        Set src = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True)
        Set ws = src.Worksheets("Fakturaunderlag")
        Set rng = ws.Range("E1")

        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        ws.Unprotect pw
        rng.value = 1
        MsgBox "Go to next file"
        src.Close (True)
        Set src = Nothing
    End If
Next

MsgBox fileCount & " files have been updated"

End Sub
```

This is before I run my code:
[image]

This is after I run my code:
[image]

This is the 'Custom' formatting that appears after update om my files:
[image]

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, the first true in workbooks.open would point at UpdateLinks, so maybe try adding local:=True `Workbooks.Open(file.Path, UpdateLinks:= True, local:=True)`

Comment: @Notus_Panda, I tried your suggestion without success unfortunately. Please read my new edits. Might that help?

Comment: That date created being so far back isn't something I'm familiar with, sorry. What's the file type you're working with?

Comment: Do your files include any event macros such as `Worksheet_Change`? When creating a new file are you doing that from a template?

Comment: @Notus_Panda I found out that the creation date wasn't the problem because the origin problem with my macro persists even if creation date is today.

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes it does. But that event macro is connected to a different worksheet than I try to update. My company uses templates (in XLStart folder) when we open excel and I found out that's why I get a very old creation date. However, that seems not be the problem that affects my updated files.

Comment: There's nothing on the code you posted which would explain the changes you're seeing on the sheet, so I'd guess the issue lies elsewhere, maybe some bug in your event procedures which gets triggered by the sheet changes.  Have you tried setting `Application.EnableEvents` to False and checking if that changes anything in what you're seeing?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, I have not tried that but I will do. The thing is that I have tried to run my code on new workbooks that doesn't includes any events at all, on three different computers. I'm starting to think this is a bug in Excel 

Comment: If you just open one of these file manually and save it, does the same change occur?

Comment: @TimWilliams, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
src.Close (True)
```

Try:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
src.SaveAs src.Path + "/" + src.Name, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Essentially you need Local to be True, which is what Notus_Panda mentioned earlier. However, it needs to be done on the save of the workbook and you cannot set this using Workbook.Save(), only SaveAs(). So unless there is another option, you have to use SaveAs() and overwrite the existing Workbook silently (if you want to simulate Save()), hence the use of Application.DisplayAlerts.

Original answer from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-savecopyas-changes-format-of-currency/43aa45e7-1cef-4014-8c3b-2ef23b055047).